# ¿Cómo validar datos en un array multidimensional? JAVA

Tags: java, array, netbeans, condiciones

Tengo una clase Cuentas con los siguientes datos encapsulados:

```
public class Cuentas {
private int nC;
private String usuario;
private String contra;
private String nombre;
private int monto;
private int tipo; [...]}
```

Éstas son mis declaraciones globales:

```
static Scanner v=new Scanner(System.in);   //Scanner de lectura de datos
public static int cnt=0;   //contador de cuentas
static int op;
public static String[][] cuentas = new String[100][6]; //Array para almacenar cuentas
```

Ahora, tengo un método para crear las cuentas, llamado crearCuentas(); respectivamente:

```
public static void crearCuenta(){
    t=new Scanner(System.in);
    int nC = cnt;
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("   --------- CREACION DE CUENTAS ---------");
    System.out.println("NOTA: el usuario debe establecerse con numeros, ej:[1111]\n");
    System.out.print("Ingrese el nuevo usuario: ");
    String usuario = t.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Ingrese la contraseña: ");
    String contra = t.nextLine();
    System.out.print("¿Quien es el titular de la nueva cuenta?: ");
    String nombre = t.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Ingrese el monto de apertura de la cuenta: ");
    int monto = t.nextInt();
    if(monto == 0){     //cambiaré el if por un do while
        System.out.println("--Usted no puede abrir la cuenta con 0 quetzales.--");
        System.out.println("Ingrese el monto de apertura de la cuenta: ");
        monto = t.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.print("Seleccione el tipo de cuenta: ");
    System.out.println("\n1.-Ahorro\n2.-Monetaria\n3.-Ahorro programado");
    System.out.print("->");
    int tipo = t.nextInt();
    nuevaCuenta(nC, usuario, contra, nombre, monto, tipo); 
    cnt++;
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
    System.out.print("Presione cualquier numero para continuar: ");
    int opn = s.nextInt();
    if(opn>=0){
        menuCuentas();
    }
}
```

Y acá registro los datos de la nueva cuenta a la clase Cuentas:

```
    public static void nuevaCuenta(int nC, String usuario, String contra, String nombre, int monto, int tipo){
    Cuentas cuenta = new Cuentas();
    cuenta.setnC(nC);
    cuenta.setUsuario(usuario);
    cuenta.setContra(contra);
    cuenta.setNombre(nombre);
}
```

Ahora acá, necesito validar los datos de *usuario* y *contraseña* para acceder a un método distinto. Traté de hacerlo con un *if* y comparar los resultados ingresados por el propio usuario para el acceso, pero todas las veces que lo he intentado me aparece el error de que usuario y contraseña son incorrectas:

```
            case 1:
            String usuariop, contrap;
            System.out.println("\n----------------------------------------------");
            System.out.print("Ingrese usuario: ");
            usuariop=u.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Ingrese contraseña: ");
            contrap=u.nextLine();
            for(int i=0;i<=cnt;i++){ //evalua segun cuantas veces cnt ha incrementado de valor
                if(usuariop.equals(cuentas[cnt][1]) &&
                        contrap.equals(cuentas[cnt][2])){ //valida usuario y contraseña
                    menuCajero();
                }else{
                    System.out.println("\nEl usuario o contraseña son incorrectos,"
                            + "por favor, intentelo de nuevo.");
                    menu();
                }
            }
            menuCajero();
            break;
```

Ya intenté comparando con las posiciones *cuentas[cnt][2]* y *cuentas[cnt][3]* pero me da el mismo error. No sé qué estoy haciendo mal, o si estoy comparando valores/posiciones correctamente.

Comment: Nunca te funcionará porque en ningún momento asignaste nada en la matriz. Cada vez que el usuario ingrese información, deberás de asignar el nombre del usuario y contraseña en X fila de la matriz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto `public static String[][] cuentas = new String[100][6];` no crea un Array de Cuentas.

Esto es un Array de 100 Cuentas `Cuentas[] cuentas = new Cuentas[100];`

Tampoco estás asignando nada al Array de Cuentas cuando creas la cuenta, deberías crear un método que crea la cuenta y la retorna, algo así:

```
public static Cuenta fabricarCuenta(int nC, String usuario, String contra, String nombre, int monto, int tipo){
    Cuentas cuenta = new Cuentas();
    cuenta.setnC(nC);
    cuenta.setUsuario(usuario);
    cuenta.setContra(contra);
    cuenta.setNombre(nombre);
    return cuenta;
}
```

Por último, cuando retornas la Cuenta debes meterla dentro del Array así que en lugar de hacer esto:

```
nuevaCuenta(nC, usuario, contra, nombre, monto, tipo);
```

haz esto:

```
cuentas[cnt] = fabricarCuenta(nC, usuario, contra, nombre, monto, tipo);
```

Para comparar el usuario y la contraseña debes crear getters en la clase Cuentas y luego hacer esto:

```
if(usuariop.equals(cuentas[cnt].getUsuario()) && contrap.equals(cuentas[cnt].getContra())){ //valida usuario y contraseña
    menuCajero();
} else {
    System.out.println("\nEl usuario o contraseña son incorrectos, por favor, intentelo de nuevo.");
    menu();
}
```

Y una pequeña sugerencia: Deberías llamar "Cuenta" a la clase "Cuentas" dado que cada instancia sería una sola cuenta y se podría prestar para confusiones cuando quieras crear una colección de cuentas.

Comment: Cambié las partes que me indicaste, pero al momento de validar el usuario me da un `NullPointerException` justo en la línea del *if*.

Comment: Debe ser que el Array de Cuentas no tiene elementos. Debes asignar elementos al array para recorrerlo, para eso es la línea `cuentas[cnt] = fabricarCuenta(nC, usuario, contra, nombre, monto, tipo);` y cada vez que agregues uno incrementa el contador `cnt++`.

Comment: Bien bien, ya llevaba registrada una cuenta, pero me lo marca como error de puntero. Y la linea de `cuentas[cnt] = fabricarCuenta(nC, usuario, contra, nombre, monto, tipo);` ya la añadí al método de petición de datos.

Comment: ¿Qué pasaría si no tengo ninguna cuenta registrada? Intenté añadiendo un `cuentas[cnt].getUsuario().isEmpty() || cuentas[cnt].getUsuario() == null` pero aún así me lanza una `NullPointerException` nuevamente.

Comment: Cuando no hay nada en el Array, cualquier intento de acceder a alguna cuenta te lanzará un `NullPointerException`. Para verificar que el campo 0 tiene una cuenta debes hacerlo asi `cuentas[0] != null`, o la cuenta en el campo 1 `cuentas[1] != null` y así con las demás hasta la 99, la 100 te lanzaría OutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 1):

Hola Oscar no te esta funcionando ya que en ningún momento agregas cuentas solo estás haciendo new cuentas. Lo que debes hacer es.

Declarar una variable global.

```
List<Cuenta> cuentas = new ArrayList< Cuentas>();
```

Posteriormente debes usar esta variable en el método nuevaCuenta

```
Cuentas cuenta = new Cuentas();
  cuenta.setnC(nC);
  cuenta.setUsuario(usuario);
  cuenta.setContra(contra);
  cuenta.setNombre(nombre);
  cuentas.add(cuenta);
```

Posteriormente en la validación  creas un método que retone un booleano

```
private Boolean validateUser(String user, String pwd){ 
 if( (null == user || null == pwd) || (user.isEmpty() || pwd.isEmpty())){
        return false;
 }
 for( Cuenta cta: cuentas){

     if ( user.equals(cta.getUsuario()) || pwd.equals(cta.getContra())){
          return true;
    }

     return false;
}
```

Y esto último usar para validar.

Comment: ¿Dentro del *if* que me retorna *true* debo poner el método al que deseo entrar con el usuario?